# How to write "IF value IN array"?

Tags: sass, conditional-statements

Hi I'm new to SASS and want to know how to write something like "`if value in array`"

For example:

```
$animal : dog;
$landAnimal : (dog, cat, lion);
$seaAnimal : (fish, squid, whale);

//keyword IN doesn't work
@if $animal in $landAnimal{
    //do something
}@else if $animal in $seaAnimal{
    //do something
}
```

I tried searching the documentation and googling but I haven't found any answers. Anyone here have solution? I believe it is quite simple.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for the `index` function:  http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#index-instance_method

```
@if index($landAnimal, $animal) {
    //do something
} @else if index($seaAnimal, $animal) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Never thought it uses that function